# Is it possible to include the script tag containing the path to dojo file inside the body tags?

Tags: dojo

I am having a parsing problem.I have Included this script tag 
 inside the body.It isnt possible for me to put it in head.

Comment: Yes, you can.  In fact, a lot of people put it inside the <head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can include Dojo pretty much anywhere. For example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/dojo.js" 
        data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");</script>
    ...
    <input type="dijit.form.TextBox" />
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to set `parseOnLoad` in your Dojo config if you want widgets in your HTML to be parsed. If this doesn't work for you, you need to describe your problem further.